# Zurb Pizza Pie chart getting enormous

Tags: javascript, html, css, zurb-foundation

So I'm trying to do this [example](http://zurb.com/playground/pizza-pie-charts) from Zurb, but when I create the pie chart (even when I copy and paste the code they have to show the example), the chart goes crazy and tries to fill up the entire page. I know that it tries to take up the entire width of the element it's under, but then when I resize the width of the element, the chart only shrinks in size, but doesn't move back up, so ultimately, it's still taking up the entire space.

This is the main code:

```
<div style="margin-left: 15px">
    <h4>Points: 3.75</h4>
    <span>Rank 4</span>

    <div class="progress success basic">
        <span class="meter" style="width: 97%">Top: 97%</span>
    </div>
    <span>Tutored 7 times</span>
    <span>Missed 2 tutoring sessions</span>

    <div class="row graphs">
        <div class="large-6 columns">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="large-2 small-4 columns">
                    <ul data-pie-id="example1">
                        <li data-value="60">Water Buffalo</li>
                        <li data-value="20">Bison</li>
                        <li data-value="12">Sheep</li>
                        <li data-value="32">Goat</li>
                        <li data-value="50">Shetland Pony</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="large-10 small-8 columns">
                    <div id="example1"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="large-6 columns">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="large-2 small-4 columns">
                    <ul data-pie-id="example2" data-options="{&quot;donut&quot;:&quot;true&quot;}">
                        <li data-value="60">Pepperoni</li>
                        <li data-value="20">Sausage</li>
                        <li data-value="12">Cheese</li>
                        <li data-value="32">Mushroom</li>
                        <li data-value="50">Chicken</li>
                        <li data-value="24">Other</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="large-10 small-8 columns">
                    <div id="example2"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My css which is under the head:

```
<link href="/res/css/pizza.css" media="screen, projector, print" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

And js which is on the bottom of the page:

```
<script src="/res/js/pizza.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/res/js/vendor/snapsvg.min.js"></script>
```

This is how it looks like:
[image: Image of how the page gets rendered]
**Edit:** Ok, so apparently when I name the id of the pie chart to 'donut', it works for some reason. I tested it by changing the ids, and only donut seems to work right now, but this won't work for me, because I have multiple pie charts needing to be shown.

**Edit2:** Seems like adding the style `max-height: 480px` seems to be a temporary fix.

Comment: Having a similar problem here using Morris.js and Foundation. Any luck coming up with a fix? @Muhatashim

Comment: @Benco The only fix I found since that day was just that temporary fix. I switched over to Google's pie chart API cause I gave up on trying to figure out what was wrong with it.

Comment: can you please post the css class of your wrapper element for the chart?

Answer (score 0):

`
    Points: 3.75
    Rank 4

```
<div class="progress success basic">
    <span class="meter" style="width: 97%">Top: 97%</span>
</div>
<span>Tutored 7 times</span>
<span>Missed 2 tutoring sessions</span>

<div class="row graphs">
    <div class="large-6 columns">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="large-2 small-4 columns">
                <ul data-pie-id="example1">
                    <li data-value="60">Water Buffalo</li>
                    <li data-value="20">Bison</li>
                    <li data-value="12">Sheep</li>
                    <li data-value="32">Goat</li>
                    <li data-value="50">Shetland Pony</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="large-10 small-8 columns">
                <div id="example1"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="large-6 columns">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="large-2 small-4 columns">
                <ul data-pie-id="example2" data-options="{&quot;donut&quot;:&quot;true&quot;}">
                    <li data-value="60">Pepperoni</li>
                    <li data-value="20">Sausage</li>
                    <li data-value="12">Cheese</li>
                    <li data-value="32">Mushroom</li>
                    <li data-value="50">Chicken</li>
                    <li data-value="24">Other</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="large-10 small-8 columns">
                <div id="example2"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

'**donut' is in your code in data-options**

Comment: It could also be the padding or margins in CSS

Answer (score 0):

Your css class 'large-10 small-8 columns' is not defined in the pizza.css, maybe you need another file like : foundation.css.

If you don't want to add that big file, try to replace or just create a new css class

```
<div class="large-10 small-8 columns">
   <div id="example1"></div>
</div>
```

By

```
<div style="width: 200px; height: 200px;">
    <div id="example1"></div>
</div>
```

or by the size that you want.